# Determine Matrix of Endomorphism given a Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Lets say that I have a vector space defined as $V:=span\{e^t, e^{2t}, te^{2t}\}$ and these 3 functions also form a Basis. Additionally, I define the endomorphism $\phi := f' + f$ over $V$, where $f'$ is the derivative of the function. How should I proceed to find the matrix that represents this endomorphism?

Here is what I got so far:

- I applied the endomorphism to all 3 basis functions and got
  $\phi(e^t)=2e^t, \phi(e^{2t})=3e^{2t}, \phi(te^{2t})=e^{2t}+3te^{2t}$
- Similarly to working with polynomials, I used the coefficients of the outputs to create the columns of the representation matrix and got $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$

Does this make sense? If not, where am I mistaken?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much! This gives me the confidence to proceed with finding eigenvalues, eigenvectors, JNF and so on.. :)